# Enable external monitors on W520 laptop running CentOS 6.4

Tags: linux, xorg, vga, xrandr

Has anyone done this?  I've googled around for hours but no luck. Some suggest to change the **BIOS "Display" settings** (to "integrated" or some other value), others suggest to use **xrandr**, others say add a file with specific lines in it (what lines?) in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d), but no amount of experimenting around has enabled my monitor yet.  Ideas?

```
xrandr -q
```

returns

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was a bug. After I set the BIOS graphics display to "discrete" and disabled VT-d it worked! It was a [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=835648)
, go figure.